# SumIfs formula with more than one "multiple criteria"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I am trying to write a formula as such:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS([SUM TOTAL], [Range 1], {[Criteria 1.1], [Criteria 1.2]}, [Range 2], [Criteria 2], [Range 3], [Criteria 3], [Range 4], {Criteria 4.1], [Criteria 4.2]}))
```

Leaving Range 4 with only 4.1 along with 1.1 and 1.2 results in 3.81 as the total, which makes sense.

Leaving Range 4 with only 4.2 along with 1.1 and 1.2 results in 4.40 as the total, which also makes sense.

However, adding in 4.1 and 4.2 with 1.1 and 1.2 results in 6.61. Why is it 6.61 and not 8.21, the sum of the two? I also have no idea how the formula returned 6.61 as none of the individual combinations without any brackets equals 6.61.

Comment: In one of your `{}` instead of `,` put `;`.  It will change the array from a vertical to a horizontal array.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Whats the logic behind that? How does a vertical array differ from a horizontal one?

Comment: I am not sure why, I just know it works.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know what to do if you had 3 criteria?

Comment: For an explanation as to two sets of OR criteria and also as to why two is the limit in this regard for COUNTIF(S)/SUMIF(S): https://excelxor.com/2014/09/28/countifs-multiple-or-criteria-for-one-or-two-criteria_ranges/. You need to switch to SUMPRODUCT for more than two.

Comment: @XORLX, Thank you!

Comment: @DrewD You're very welcome!

Comment: @ScottCraner That might be a good answer for future readers...

Comment: @XORLX, amazing post. Just RSSd to your blog.

Comment: @DougGlancy Thanks! Glad you think so!

Answer (score 0):

Since there is only 2 Criteria options for range 1 & 4, why not just produce 4 sumif() function and add them? I mean for 1st sumif() include Criteria 1.1 for Range 1 & Criteria 4.1 for range 4 . For 2nd sumif() > Criteria 1.1 for Range 1 & Criteria 4.2 for range 4 . For 3rd sumif() > Criteria 1.2 for Range 1 & Criteria 4.1 for range 4 . And for 4th sumif() > Criteria 1.2 for Range 1 & Criteria 4.2 for range 4 .

```
=SUMIFS([SUM TOTAL], [Range 1], [Criteria 1.1], [Range 2], [Criteria 2], [Range 3], [Criteria 3], [Range 4], [Criteria 4.1])
+ SUMIFS([SUM TOTAL], [Range 1], [Criteria 1.1], [Range 2], [Criteria 2], [Range 3], [Criteria 3], [Range 4], [Criteria 4.2])
+ SUMIFS([SUM TOTAL], [Range 1], [Criteria 1.2], [Range 2], [Criteria 2], [Range 3], [Criteria 3], [Range 4], [Criteria 4.1])
+ SUMIFS([SUM TOTAL], [Range 1], [Criteria 1.2], [Range 2], [Criteria 2], [Range 3], [Criteria 3], [Range 4], [Criteria 4.2])
```